# How to make dateTime picker as required field in moment & AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, datetime, dom-events

I have one form that includes jQuery moment.js date-time picker I need to make this field required and disable the submit button until date time is not been picked by the user.

However, the approach that I am following is not working.

Here is my code -

```
<form name="myForm">
    <div ng-show="myData.type==='PHONE'" class="col-md-12">
        <div ng-if="myData.condition1 ==='something'" class="position-relative form-group">
            <label for="email" class="">First Value</label>
            <select name="firstValue"
                    id="firstValue"
                    ng-model="Data.firstValue"
                    class="form-control" required>
                <option value="none">None</option>
                <option value="done">Done</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div ng-if="myData.condition2==='somethingElse'" class="position-relative form-group"><label
                    for="email"
                    class="">Second Value</label>
            <input name="secondValue"
                   id="secondValue"
                   ng-model="Data.secondValue"
                   class="form-control" required>
        </div>
        <div ng-show="myData.condition3==='importantCondition'" class="position-relative form-group">
            <label class="w-100" for="email">Third Value i.e Date & Time </label>
            <div class="input-group date" id="thirdValue">
                <input  type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS A"/>
                <div class="input-group-addon input-group-append">
                    <div class="input-group-text">
                        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="myData.type==='EMAIL'" class="col-md-12">
        //Other conditions
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
            <input id="btn" class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" value="Submit" ng-click="submitData(Data)">
    </div>
    </form>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#thirdValue').datetimepicker({
                "keepOpen":false,
                "format": 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss A',
                "useCurrent": false,
                "sideBySide": false,
                "widgetPositioning": {
                    horizontal: 'right',
                    vertical: 'bottom'
                },
                "icons": {
                    time: "fa fa-clock-o",
                    date: "fa fa-calendar",
                }
            }).on("dp.change", function (e) {
                var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("angularController")).scope();
                if($('#thirdValue').datetimepicker('date')!==null) {
                    scope.Data.dateTime = $('#thirdValue').datetimepicker('date').utc()
                    var temp = $('#thirdValue').datetimepicker('date').utc()
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        })

    </script>
```

I want submit button to remain disabled until I don't select values for all the required fields.

Comment: 1) `document.read()` needs to be `document.ready()` 2) Why are you using jQuery AND Angular? That's a big code smell.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Sorry I miss typed while asking. This is not an issue in my code I updated the question.
Actually I am working on legacy code that's how it was, already.
Should I not use jQuery here? How will I do this then